# Move next Dateadd to Monday only if it falls on Saturday and Sunday

Tags: vba, excel, date

I would like the following code to return Monday date ***only*** if dateadd hits Saturday and Sunday. Unfortunately, now it returns Monday at all times even though dateadd doesn't fall on a Saturday or Sunday date.

Is it anyway to improve this code in order to return Monday ***only*** when needed?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)


 Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, d3 As Date

    d1 = NextMonday(Date, 1)
    d2 = NextMonday(Date, 7)
    d3 = NextMonday(Date, 5)

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("H3:H150")) Is Nothing Then
        If target.Value = 7 Then
        target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d2
        ElseIf target.Value = 5 Then
        target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d3
        ElseIf target.Value = 1 Then
        target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d1
        Else
        End If
    End If
  End Sub

Function NextMonday(dtDate As Date, lngDaysToAdd As Long)
    Dim intDaysOffset As Integer
    NextMonday = DateAdd("d", lngDaysToAdd, dtDate)
    intDaysOffset = (7 - Weekday(NextMonday, vbMonday)) + 1
    NextMonday = DateAdd("d", intDaysOffset, NextMonday)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having found your "landing date", you can use this generic function to return the Monday should the date be a weekend day:

```
Public Function DateSkipWeekend( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booReverse As Boolean) _
  As Date

' Purpose: Calculate first working day equal to or following/preceding datDate.
' Assumes: 5 or 6 working days per week. Weekend is (Saturday and) Sunday.
' Limitation: Does not count for public holidays.
'
' May be freely used and distributed.
' 1999-07-03, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, Copenhagen

  Const cintWorkdaysOfWeek As Integer = 5

  Dim bytSunday   As Byte
  Dim bytWeekday  As Byte

  bytSunday = Weekday(vbSunday, vbMonday)
  bytWeekday = Weekday(datDate, vbMonday)

  If bytWeekday > cintWorkdaysOfWeek Then
    ' Weekend.
    If booReverse = False Then
      ' Get following workday.
      datDate = DateAdd("d", 1 + bytSunday - bytWeekday, datDate)
    Else
      ' Get preceding workday.
      datDate = DateAdd("d", cintWorkdaysOfWeek - bytWeekday, datDate)
    End If
  End If

  DateSkipWeekend = datDate

End Function
```

And in your function:

```
Function NextMonday(dtDate As Date, lngDaysToAdd As Long)
    NextMonday = DateSkipWeekend(DateAdd("d", lngDaysToAdd, dtDate))
End Function
```

Comment: Please how would you introduce this function in my sub code? Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Really greatful

Answer (score 0):

Check the resulting day and set the return value accordingly. But of course, your function should be *renamed*, I suggest `NextWorkday` because you want to skip only weekend days.

```
Function NextWorkday(dtDate As Date, lngDaysToAdd As Long)
    NextWorkday = dtDate + lngDaysToAdd
    Select Case Weekday(NextWorkday, vbMonday)
      Case 6: NextWorkday = NextWorkday + 2
      Case 7: NextWorkday = NextWorkday + 1
    End Select
End Function
```

---

I'm not sure why you are updating only for some values, but if you still want this checking, your code can be translated to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column <> Columns("H").Column Then Exit Sub
  Select Case Target.Value2
    Case 1, 5, 7: Target.Offset(0, 1).value = NextWorkday(Date, Target.Value2)
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please how would you introduce this function in my sub code? Many thanks

Comment: @Tom is there a reason you are updating only if `Target.Value` is `1, 5, or 7`? Or was that for trying to solve the same problem?

Comment: Those value correspond to a follow up date adding. Those value are important for me to set up the next follow up date. Therefore target.value=1 stands for in 1 day, =5 in 5 days, =7in 7 days. They are part of the same problem. Next follow up date if it target value is 5, in 5 days,I would like to return on Monday rather than Sunday and so on

Comment: @Tom try the added last part of the answer. But I'm still unclear as to why if value is `4` or `2`, dont you also want to find next in 4 days, or 2 days etc? Only when it is `1, 5 or 7`??

Comment: These 1, 5, 7 days are a drop down list option that belongs

Comment: @Tom ok, so did the modified `Worksheet_Change` procedure work for you?

Comment: These values 1, 5, 7 days belong to a drop down list menu and are part of a follow up multisciplinary set up time table to review patients. It's meant to be actually 1,3,7 but to show that my code doesn't  work on Saturday and Sunday as I would I have changed 3 in 5 to make it fall on weekend. If it works with other date adding date I'm happy but mainly I'm concerned with these 3 values now

Comment: I'm going to try it tomorrow and let you know the result asap. Many thanks

Comment: Hi ASH I have tried your code and it works amazingly. Many thanks

Comment: Hi @Tom. Glad to know that.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add 0 to same code to add date same Day? Many thanks

Comment: Yes I will do it

Comment: @Tom `Case 0, 1, 5, 7:`? You can also drop the `Select Case` altogether.

Comment: Really kind of you. Many thanks again. I have marked it. Have a good day. Thanks for your wonderful help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in Excel function `Workday`:

```
Function NextMonday(dtDate As Date, lngDaysToAdd As Long) As Date
    NextMonday = Application.WorkDay(dtDate + lngDaysToAdd - 1, 1)
End Function
```

The subtraction of 1 from the future date is to allow one workday to be added.  (Adding zero workdays to a date that is a Saturday/Sunday would return the Saturday/Sunday.)

(And, as A.S.H suggested, it would be a good idea to rename that Function as it doesn't return "next Monday".)

---

However, if I am reading your VBA code correctly, you may be able to just use `WORKDAY` in an Excel cell, e.g. in cell `I3` use

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY()+H3-1,1)
```